# PowerShell: Adding filter or query to Get-WmiObject

Tags: powershell, wmi

I'm trying to add a filter or query to a line of PowerShell code, but I am getting weird results.  I can replicate this problem using any WMI query.  Here is an example:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Processor -Namespace root\cimv2 -filter 'Status = `"OK`"'"
```

That gives me this error: Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "select * from Win32_Processor where Status = OK".  But if I run it in a PowerShell window that is already open, like this:

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Processor -Namespace root\cimv2 -filter 'Status = "OK"'
```

That works fine.  So I am not understanding this behavior.  I tried every manner of single quotes, double quotes, and escape characters, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Your syntax for the query is wrong: `-Filter 'Name LIKE "Drivers - %"'`

Comment: I tried it with LIKE too but it did not work.  For some reason it works fine without using powershell.exe -command to start it, but not with.

Comment: Your statement didn't make any sense. How are you actually calling this?

Comment: I changed the question to a more simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a misunderstanding of quoting with the cmd parser (as that's what is used when calling powershell.exe):

```
powershell.exe -Command ""
```

Everything between the double-quotes will be passed to `-Command`.  In your case, the easiest route to go will be escaping single-quotes (by doubling the count) since cmd handles double-quotes in a special way (usually, by removing them):

```
powershell.exe -Command "Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor -Filter 'Status = ''OK'''"
```

As a footnote, `root/cimv2` is the default namespace for `Get-WmiObject`

Comment: I think that was my problem, I didn't know you could escape single quotes by doubling them.  I thought you had to use the tilde just like you do for double quotes.